# Database initialization failure in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a small test site in mvc.
I've created the model as :

```
  public class Subject_Master
    {
        public Subject_Master()
        {
        }
        public Subject_Master(string Subject_Name)
        {
            this.Subject_Name = Subject_Name;
        }
        public int Subject_MasterId { get; set; }
        public string Subject_Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Context is :

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<StudentAccount> StudentAccount { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Subject_Master> Subject_Master { get; set; }
    }
```

The initializer :

```
namespace MyProj.Models
{
    public class DBInitializer:DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<XpertsContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(XpertsContext context)
        {
            var Subject_Master_List = new List<Subject_Master>();

            Subject_Master_List.Add(new Subject_Master("English"));
            Subject_Master_List.Add(new Subject_Master("Hindi"));
            Subject_Master_List.Add(new Subject_Master("Bengali"));

            foreach (var subject in Subject_Master_List)
            {
                context.Subject_Master.Add(subject);
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The database is created but the data is not getting inserted.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to use this `DBInitializer` class that you wrote. In your `Application_Start` you could specify the desired initializer using the [`SetInitializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461(v=vs.113).aspx) static method:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DBInitializer());
```

Also don't forget that the initializer's `Seed` method will be called the first time a query is made against `MyContext`, not when your application starts.

Alternatively you could specify the initializer in your web.config file as shown [`here`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx#Initializers).

Comment: I did that. But now when I ran the project, it didn't insert the data. How ever when I deleted the entire db, and re-ran the project. it got inserted. Is there any way, where, if the db is created already, the data will be inserted without having to delete/re-create db ?

Comment: That's normal, look what class you have derived from: `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`. The `IfModelChanges` part is important. You probably need [`DropCreateDatabaseAlways`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679506(v=vs.113).aspx) if you want your database to be always recreated when the context is first used.